# visual studio code ,access firebase config file that's in the back end from the front end project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a front end and back end project

I started the project by using the firebase config file in the back end

Back End

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import "@firebase/storage"
import '@firebase/firestore'

//Your Web App's Firebase Configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBEkSLuI3itUsX3iIhvDnnHHT7WoCT76qI",
    authDomain: "workservices-e4506.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://workservices-e4506.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "workservices-e4506",
    storageBucket: "workservices-e4506.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "232325006209",
    appId: "1:232325006209:web:da0aca044337ef4b119e80",
    measurementId: "G-K8BRW9Y8HL"
  };

//Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
const  projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp;

export {projectStorage, projectFirestore, timestamp}
```

now I want to try access the config file by using a function in the front end to reach the database

but obvious to some when i have a seperate config file in the front end project i get the error:

Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).

how can i get around this?/ how can i access the backend config file from the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to have two different projects for front end and back end, but you can create multiple firebase projects by giving it a name when initializing like this:

```
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");
```

You can read more about initializing multiple firebase projects [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#web)

Comment: dshukertjr I have a node.js functions project that has endpoints that send and receive data with the firebase database then i have a front end project, is this the correct terminology?

Comment: @benpalmer It still sounds like you should use single firebase app for both front and back end. These front and back end are both for the same app, right?

Comment: yes, though the in the tutorial I learnt with it advised have a seperate back end , this will make the app faster, as a mobile won't have to download a huge app and then the api can communicate with the database , does this sound right?    obviously not needed for a practice app but perhaps for a large real world app.

Comment: @benpalmer No, it does not sounds right. You may be confusing something. You can have back end using cloud functions and front end live in a single project. This would not slow down anything no matter how big the project grows.

Comment: Having a back and and a front end does not mean you need two separate projects. These can and should live under one project if they are for the same app.